# Parallel processing with Python on Zeit Now serverless

Tags: python, vercel

Is it possible to use parallel processing (e.g. threads, processes, async tasks) in a Python program running on the serverless platform Zeit Now?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's currently not possible to use any parallel processing features like processes, threads or async tasks in programs running on the Now platform.

Note that programs with those features will not produce any errors or warning though. The part that would invoke the parallel processing will just not be executed.

This behavior is currently only sparsely documented (indirectly mentioned [here](https://zeit.co/docs/v2/platform/upgrade-to-2-0/?query=queue#no-daemons)), but I got it confirmed on the internal support forum from the devs. They also say that they are aware that this is a critical feature and are working to add solutions like queues.

Answer on support forum:

> Due to the environment, it is not possible to do that. once you
>   respond the process is terminated.
>
> You are looking for queue support, which will be released soon.

Comment: Someone down voted this answer. Care to leave a comment with a reason?